# Syntax error Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: asp.net, sql

As the title says, I'm getting a syntax error when trying to execute the following insert query against an MS Access database from an ASP.NET page.

```
sqls = "INSERT INTO Invoice(Date, S_OF, Consignee_name, Vechile_type, Make, Model, 
                            Chassis_no, Transmission, Fuel_Type, Mile_age, Colour, 
                            Engine_type, Wheel_Drive, Accesories_options, FOB_Price, 
                            Fright_Price, Insurance, inspection, Port_of_Loading, 
                            Destination, Drive, Total)
        VALUES('" + date1.Text + "','" + Sof.Text + "','" + consigneee.Text + "','" + 
               dvtype.Text + "','" + make.Text + "','" + Model.Text + "','" + chassisno.Text + 
               "','" + dtransmision.Text + "','" + dfueltype.Text + "','" + mileage.Text + "','" 
               + dcolour.Text + "','" + enginetype.Text + "','" + dwheeldrive.Text + "','" 
               + labelc.Text + "','" + FobPrice.Text + "','" + frieghtprice.Text + "','" 
               + insurance.Text + "','" + inspection.Text + "','" + portofloading.Text 
               + "','" + portdestination.Text + "','" + ddrive.Text + "','" + total.Text + "')"
```

Comment: change that query to use parameters! And what error did you get?

Comment: Yes, please, use parameters.  Read up on sql injection.

Comment: Post the exact error message. It's slightly ironic that the only tag you have used is `error-message`, yet you didn't post the error message in your question.

Comment: [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: this was the error message:

Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing here since you haven't provided the error message but you seem to have a few typos in the column names.

```
"INSERT INTO Invoice(Date,S_OF,Consignee_name,Vechile_type,Make,...
                                              ^^^^^^^
```

Did you mean `Vehicle`?

```
Accesories_options
```

It should be spelled `Accessories`.

```
Fright_Price
```

Do you really charge people to be scared? I'm sure you meant `Freight_Price` here.

Comment: *Bad speller of the world - untie!* :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can you String.Format("INSERT INTO Invoice Values {0}{1}{2}", value0, value1, value2 ) so value0 will replace for {0}, value1 will replace for {1} and so on. That's way you can trace the error better.

Further more, try to use store-procedure and parameters to avoid sql injection. It's worth to spend sometimes on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how someone can possibly hack into your database (SQL injection). Please note it is provided for educational purposes! Do not try to execute it!

If someone enters this into your **total** Textbox, your data may be deleted:

```
'); delete from invoice; print ('hi
```

Ironically, couple years ago I got error message on the web site where I ordered parts for my car (Mopar parts seller). I got error like "...error in WHERE clause...". So, it was open for SQL injection attack. I sent them email but never ordered from them again. I hope, you are not representing them here :)